# S3 hosted website only accessible via Private Endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, vpc-endpoint

I have a task to host a website on S3 which is only accessible via the private link.

I created the website, and I am able to access it using the public link
Link --> http://mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I also created a VPC interface endpoint to access the bucket privately over the VPN. I got the DNS name from the Interface endpoint as
*.vpce-xxxxx-xxx.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com

I did the nslookup on the mywebsite.com.vpce-xxxxx-xxx.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com and is getting the correct IP addresses of the ENI's

When I try to access the webite thru the VPC Interface endpoint I am getting bucket does not exist. What I am doing wrong ?

I am using this url to access the bucket.

Link : http://mywebsite.com.vpce-xxxxx-xxx.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com

For this POC my bucket policy is wide open so there is no restriction on the bucket policy.

Comment: Hi Vipin, were you able to figure this out? We are facing the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/privatelink-interface-endpoints.html#accessing-bucket-and-aps-from-interface-endpoints

> AWS PrivateLink for Amazon S3 does not support the following:
>
> - Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) endpoints
> - Website endpoints
> - Legacy global endpoints
> - Using CopyObject API or UploadPartCopy API between buckets in different AWS Regions
> - Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0