# Create VPC Endpoint for s3-website, not s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public s3 static website, and I want to hide the public default URL so that it's only viewable via my own reverse-proxy using a VPC endpoint.

It's currently working right now using the URL for standard bucket access: `my-bucket.bucket.vpce-xxxxxxxxxx.s3.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com`, however this is allowing directory browsing publicly.

Is it possible to create an endpoint for the `s3-website` version instead of `s3` so that directories will route to `index.html`? There is absolutely nothing in the AWS docs that I can find referring to `s3-website` endpoints, just standard `s3` endpoints.

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69451314/s3-hosted-website-only-accessible-via-private-endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as "s3-website" VPC endpoint.

**The following method only works for gateway VPC endpoint for S3**

You can attach the following bucket policy to your bucket which has static website hosting enabled,

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*",
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
           "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

then use the bucket website endpoint (e.g. In us-east-1, http://xxx.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com) to visit your website. Now, internet traffic will be blocked and you can use the VPC endpoint for S3 to access your website privately. Cheers!

Comment: I've tried exactly this already and the VPC gets denied access unless it uses the endpoint URL, and the endpoint URL allows directory listing.

Comment: @chrispytoes Please read my answer carefully, you should use the bucket website endpoint.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, when my proxy upstream is set to the `s3-website` URL, it gets denied access because `aws:SourceVpce` just checks if the request is coming from the endpoint URL. The `s3-website` URL always routes via the internet, so it cannot be used from within the VPC if the bucket it restricted to the endpoint only. If the bucket is restricted to a VPC Endpoint, then the requests MUST come from the endpoint URL.

Comment: @chrispytoes This method only works if you use a gateway endpoint for S3. It doesn't work for the interface endpoint.

Comment: Okay I've changed it to a Gateway endpoint but now I'm just getting a `Bad Gateway` error.

Comment: @chrispytoes Can you clear the DNS cache and try again?

Comment: Okay now it's just timing out entirely on both the Amazon URL, and my proxy URL.

Comment: Ah, but the standard non-website URL works fine. It seems s3-website does not work with Gateway endpoints either?

Comment: @chrispytoes No, I've tested and it works perfectly. Can you do a `dig` on the bucket endpoint hostname?

Comment: `my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` gives 52.219.108.24, and `my-bucket.s3-website-us-east-2.amazonaws.com` is not found. The first one is the one that's timing out.

Comment: @chrispytoes Looks like the Static website hosting of your bucket is not enabled.

Comment: Is is though, I can access it on the `my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` URL when I set its policy to public. It only gives errors when it's restricted to the endpoint.

Comment: @chrispytoes Oh, i see. The website url in us-east-2 is a little bit different. Stick to the `my-bucket.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` format.

Comment: Yes I have been, still have the timing out on that URL though.

Comment: @chrispytoes Could you verify the route table has a route to the s3 gateway endpoint?

Comment: Yeah I'll be honest I set up the whole VPC with an existing Terraform module. I'm still learning how route tables or any of this networking stuff works. However I'm seeing in the AWS docs that it should add the route automatically.

Comment: Okay sorry figured it out. Yes I have a prefix for `com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3` in the route table. Is that it?

Comment: Yep, are you using http instead of https?

Comment: @jellycsc Getting access denied, while trying to access my private bucket staticwebsite using URL like- http://xyz.vpce-12345.s3.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com

Comment: @gauravagnihotri you need to use the bucket website endpoint